# How to pipe in data to dockerified app on docker run?

Tags: docker, pipe

I have dockerified [httpie](https://httpie.org) via this [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/k0pernikus/httpie-docker-alpine/~/dockerfile/):

```
FROM alpine:3.6
MAINTAINER Philipp Kretzschmar <philipp.kretzschmar@gmail.com>
ENV LAST_UPDATED=2017-06-01
ARG XDG_CACHE_HOME=/tmp/cache/
RUN apk update && \
    apk add py-pip && pip install httpie && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
CMD ["--help"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/http"]
```

You can also pull the image directly:

```
docker pull k0pernikus/httpie-docker-alpine:1.0.0
```

Using httpie as a standalone program, I know it is recommended to pipe in a nested json payload via echo (simplified example):

```
$ echo '{"property":"value"}' | http PUT https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com -vvv
```

And through the verbose output flag `-vvv` httpie shows that the payload was indeed sent in the request:

```
PUT /posts HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/json
Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.9

{
    "property": "value"
}
```

(The jsonplaceholder URL will return 404, which is fine. This question's scope is only about sending the proper request.)

Now I thought that it would be equivalent to execute the command through docker via:

```
$ echo '{"property":"value"}' | docker run k0pernikus/httpie-docker-alpine:1.0.0 PUT https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com -vvv
```

But the verbose flag reports that the request was send without the payload:

```
PUT / HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
Accept: */*
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.9
Connection: keep-alive
```

How can I pipe in the data to the `docker run` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `-i` flag to `docker run` in order to keep `stdin` open.  Compare:

```
$ echo hello | docker run --rm alpine cat
$
```

To:

```
$ echo hello | docker run -i --rm alpine cat
hello
$
```

Comment: I was about to write that I tried this. Then I realized, I was adding the flag to the httpie command m)